# Get protractor to evaluate an element's isolateScope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have an e2e test that just began failing. It looks something like this:

```
myPageInstance.myDirectiveWithIsolateScope.evaluate("myIsolateScopeProperty")
.then(function(myIsolateScopeProperty) {
    expect(myIsolateScopeProperty.someKey).toEqual('');
})
```

If I throw a `ptor.debugger()` in there I can use the dev tools to see that:

```
angular.element(myElementWithIsolateScopeDirective)
    .scope().myIsolateScopeProperty === 'undefined'
```

however:

```
angular.element(myElementWithIsolateScopeDirective)
    .isolateScope().myIsolateScopeProperty == {someKey:''}
```

I think maybe this is due to [a breaking change in Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1), but then again I'd be lying if I said I fully understood their description.